# Bad state:Tried to use ConfirmBookingController after dipose was called

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Bad state: Tried to use ConfirmBookingController after dispose was called.

I/flutter ( 1113):

I/flutter ( 1113): Consider checking mounted.

E/flutter ( 1113): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use ConfirmBookingController after dispose was called.

E/flutter ( 1113):

E/flutter ( 1113): Consider checking mounted.

E/flutter ( 1113):

E/flutter ( 1113): #0   StateNotifier._debugIsMounted. (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:175:9)

E/flutter ( 1113): #1   StateNotifier._debugIsMounted (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:182:6)

E/flutter ( 1113): #2   StateNotifier.state (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:197:12)

E/flutter ( 1113): #3   ConfirmBookingController.confirmBooking (package:property/controllers/confirm_payment.dart:64:15)

E/flutter ( 1113):

How to solve this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.